# In R, how can I change the number of X variables used in a lm regression equation that nested within a list held within a function?

Tags: list, lm

I have written a function in R that reads factors from one data.frame (the X's) and asset class returns from another data.frame (the Y's) with the goal of running a series of linear regressions.  Using a list() command,  I have been able to use each column within the asset class return data.frame as a Y and have written a formula using the investment factors as the X's from the other data.frame.  I wrote this as a function so that I can easily move between different data.frames and obtain different result easily. My issue is that within the lm, the number of X's to include is influenced by the number of factors I have within the data.frame.  For example if I have 8 factors, I want to obtain results using 4 X's within the lm.  In another file, I will have 20 factors so I want to include 7 X's in the lm.  The problem is that I need to manually change the X's within the lm when I move between files and then have to rerun the function.

How do I change the formula within the list to automatically use the X's I identify in the function input?

Here is some sample data

FactorsCPI8Inf.df
PC1          PC2          PC3          PC4           PC5           PC6           PC7           PC8
1 0.006103804 -0.003261693  0.005467668 0.0023000312 -0.0026939347 -0.0025971692 -0.0007092999  0.0021463974
2 0.005557393  0.002172815  0.005549971 0.0012424813  0.0027123043 -0.0005173716  0.0009768670  0.0018525702
3 0.009111751 -0.001411228  0.004405017 0.0012565142 -0.0034679402 -0.0054461527 -0.0002898188  0.0018169942
4 0.007198568  0.002761386  0.003895265 0.0029572720 -0.0006881223 -0.0009866646  0.0008075030 -0.0001030015
5 0.009284388  0.003610756 -0.001604478 0.0004870507  0.0046594613  0.0012563786 -0.0035364638  0.0050812669
6 0.010176900  0.001401130  0.001915809 0.0018111569 -0.0028201181  0.0027314130 -0.0009541055  0.0009042990
ACR8df
KF_Mkt_TR_lrf EmMarkTR_lrf DevMarkxNaTR_lrf KF_RlEst_TR_lrf DJCorpBondTR_lrf USTreasuryAveTR_lrf CommodityAllTR_lrf DXYextGFD_TR_lrf
[1,]      0.007657  0.014624575      0.003124846        0.039057     -0.003759870        -0.011376222       7.249727e-05     -0.004410278
[2,]      0.040107  0.001501342      0.002197864        0.049407      0.003426239         0.010167556      -2.202028e-03     -0.003859931
[3,]      0.038756  0.008354458      0.012889433        0.033056     -0.004298806        -0.013099222      -7.226050e-03     -0.003928356
[4,]     -0.043126 -0.009257993      0.010623874        0.127474     -0.018434261        -0.001192889       2.312022e-02     -0.003794226
[5,]      0.024126  0.017218604      0.003210113        0.014226     -0.008480430        -0.017021556      -5.960944e-03     -0.002757584
[6,]      0.045747  0.004385590      0.009438711        0.074347     -0.003221508         0.006005444       4.307120e-02     -0.002567862

Here is the code:

Output <- function(PCAfactors, NACRs, Input-for-lmXs) {

```
    alldata <-cbind(NACRs,PCAfactors)
    dim(alldata)
    storage <- list()
    for(i in names(alldata)){storage[[i]] <- lm(get(i) ~ PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4, alldata)}
    storage
    lapply(storage,FUN=summary) 
    resultscoef <- map(storage, ~ summary(.x)$coefficients[,1])
    resultscoef.df <-data.frame(resultscoef)
    resultscoef.df.2 <-data.frame(resultscoef.df)[(2:nrow(resultscoef.df)),c(1:ncol(NACRs))]
    resultscoef.df.2.trans <- t(resultscoef.df.2)
    dim(resultscoef.df.2.trans) # (N X K) N = # test assets K = # of PCs
    FMBetastep1.M = as.matrix(resultscoef.df.2.trans)
   return(FMBetastep1.M)
   }
```

In the function, PCAfactors would be equal to the FactorsCPI8Inf.df data and NACRs would be equal to the ACR8df data.  All data within FactorsCPI8Inf.df is named PC1 to PC8 so within the lm equation above, the X's are represented by PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4.  If a different input file was used this might be PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4+PC5+PC6+PC7.  The Input-for-lmX's input within the function is just a placeholder for the number of X's; it is not actually used within the function right now because I am unable to get it to work.

I have tried to use the variable names within the input function but it does not properly read in the information.  This is what that looked like:

Output <- function(FactorsCPI8Inf.df data, ACR8df, PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4)

and the list was changed to:
storage <- list()
for(i in names(alldata)){storage[[i]] <- lm(get(i) ~ Input-for-lmXs, alldata)}
storage

The overall function produces the results I am looking for, I'm just looking for assistance with the automation of changing the lm function within the ln() code.

I would greatly appreciate any help.